# Deselect all items in Form Control Listbox

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using a multi-select Listbox (a Form control, not an ActiveX) on my spreadsheet. I need a macro to deselect all the items in the list.

From what I've read, this should work:

```
    For i = 0 To ActiveSheet.Shapes("List Box 28").ListCount - 1
       ActiveSheet.Shapes("List Box 28").Selected(i) = False
    Next
```

But the first two lines tell me *Object doesn't support this property or method*.  I suspect this code applies only to `ActiveX`, but I can't seem to find the right ones for Form controls.

Comment: Is there a SelectionMode or Style or something?  Maybe you need to toggle the Selection Mode so that **none** can be selected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("List Box 28").OLEFormat.Object.ListIndex = 0
```

You will have to invoke first the `OLEFormat Object` before you can use the *List box property*.

Also to make your loop work, you can try below:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim lb As ListBox '/* Declare a listbox object */

With ActiveSheet.Shapes("List Box 28")
    Set lb = .OLEFormat.Object '/* set to make intellisense  kick in */
    With lb
        For i = 1 To .ListCount '/* indexing starts at 1 and not 0 */
            .Selected(i) = False
        Next
    End With
End With
```

But if you're just deselecting all that is selected, use the first code.
I just showed the looping in case it has some use for you and others in the future.